# Write API syntax correctly in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js, rest

I'm learning next js and Rest API but I'm confused about the syntax ,as default next js have a dynamic root so we use like this `/api/etc/[test]`

But when I'm learning rest Api in another website, there is a different syntax

```
/api/help/:id

or

/api/book/?=test
```

why in the example above there is have `:`,`?` and `=` ?
What the best syntax for get data, filter or post and etc from server?

Comment: There are just different ways of define where properties should be placed. If the question is why there is a different pattern, the answer is preference...

Comment: what is :,?,= , what is that mean and when to use that ? @ChristianMoen

Comment: From what I understand, :id maps to the parameter of id, and `?` is the default way of stating parameters in a get request..

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html